# Transfer log file between client and server while updating files automatically

Tags: java, socket

All this code does is transfer the files.  In order to make changes to the file, one has to re-transfer the file.  During this time, I stand by to automate the update operation, where the server listens to the files and updates them automatically whenever any changes are made.

```
fileserver.java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileServer {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(13850);// creating a new serversocket
        System.out.println("Server started.");
} catch (Exception e)// catches errors and display them to the user for eg in case the port is busy we may specify a different port
{
        System.err.println("Port already in use.");
        System.exit(1);
}

    while (true)
{
try {
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();// establishing the connection
System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + clientSocket);

Thread t = new Thread(new CLIENTConnection(clientSocket));
/*creating thread for clientconnection.java file and sending socket as an object thus everytime a connection is established a new thread/process is generated through which the file is sent and recieved*/
t.start();// executing the thread. here the new process or thread is created and ready to be implemented

} catch (Exception e) // catches error if any and displays it in the terminal/command prompt
{
System.err.println("Error in connection attempt.");
}
}
}
}

clientconnection.java
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.String;



public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable {

private Socket clientSocket;
private BufferedReader in = null;

public CLIENTConnection(Socket client) {
this.clientSocket = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
clientSocket.getInputStream()));

receiveFile();

in.close();

}


catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}

public void receiveFile() {
try {
int bytesRead;
DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_client_" + fileName));
long size = clientData.readLong();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
size -= bytesRead;
}

output.close();
clientData.close();

System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from client.");
} catch (IOException ex) {
System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
}
}


}

filecliet.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class FileClient {

private static Socket sock;// defining a socket
private static String fileName;// defining a file
private static BufferedReader stdin;// creating a buffered reader object to take and read the input from the users
private static PrintStream os;// creating an object of printstream to display text or output in the terminal/command prompt

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
try {
sock = new Socket("localhost", 13850);// creating a socket specifying the port and the ip address of the server to the client
stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
} catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later."+e);
        System.exit(1);
}

os = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

try {

sendFile();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("not valid input");
}


sock.close();
}



public static void sendFile() {
try {
System.err.print("Enter file name: ");
fileName = stdin.readLine();//reads the file entered by the user 


File myFile = new File(fileName);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];//determining the lenght of the file

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);//creating an input stream to read the contents of the file
//bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

//Sending file name and file size to the server
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);//creating an output stream to send the file to the server
dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);//writing the contents of the file to the server
dos.flush();
System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to Server.");
} catch (Exception e) {                           //reports error if any
System.err.println("File does not exist!"); 
}
}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your socket communication protocol is asymmetrical..... the client-side cannot correctly send files larger than 2GB (though the server side looks like it can handle it).

Additionally, your client-side code reads the entire file in to memory.... which is wasteful and unnecessary.

Using the functions available in Java7, you should be using try-with-resources. As it is, you are not closing your sockets correctly, and you're not closing file-handles right either.

Additionally, your methods should complete just a single function. Your sendFile method does user-input as well as the network transfer. I would recommend that you take the user-input out of the method. The receiveFile side of things also has hard-coded file names and locations. I recommend parameterizing it.

Finally, you do not do anything to trap problems with file-changes that may happen mid-transfer, and your error-handling in general is a problem.

I have taken these two methods and re-structured them in a way that:

- has single functionality in each method.
- does correct resource-closing (even in exceptional conditions)
- is symmetrical (you can send and receive large files)
- handles cases where the file changes mid-send, or is not completely received.
- uses the socket send/recieve buffer-sizes to set the right size byte-buffer arrays

The methods take some input parameters that are not part of your specification. This is to ensure single-responsibility is maintained.

The exception handling is still not great, but would need to conform to your overall system.

Consider the methods...

### receiveFile:

```
public static final void receiveFile(File outdir, Socket sock) {
    try (DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()))) {

        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        
        try (OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outdir, "received_from_client_" + fileName)))) {
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            long bytesRemaining = size;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sock.getReceiveBufferSize()];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while (bytesRemaining > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, bytesRemaining))) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
            }
            output.flush();
            if (bytesRemaining > 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read entire file, missing " + bytesRemaining + " bytes");
            }
            if (clientData.read() >= 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected bytes still on the input from the client");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Unexpected Client error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

### sendFile:

```
public static void sendFile(String fileName, String host, int port) throws IOException {

    File myFile = new File(fileName);
    long expect = myFile.length();
    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()))) {
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sock.getSendBufferSize()];
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(expect);
        
        long left = expect;
        int inlen = 0;
        while (left > 0 && (inlen = bis.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(left, buffer.length))) >= 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, inlen);
            left -= inlen;
        }
        dos.flush();
        if (left > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("We expected " + expect + " bytes but came up short by " + left);
        }
        if (bis.read() >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("We expected only " + expect + " bytes, but additional data has been added to the file");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this using some junk data I have, and the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    File outdir = new File("copiedfiles");
    if (!outdir.isDirectory()) {
        outdir.mkdirs();
    }
    
    final int port = 13850;
    final String host = "localhost";
    
    Runnable client = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                sendFile("core.20131214.230701.4868.0001.dmp", host, port);
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    
    Thread clientthread = new Thread(client);
    clientthread.setDaemon(true);
    clientthread.start();
    
    try (ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        Socket clientsock = ssocket.accept();
        receiveFile(outdir, clientsock);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```